# Hadoop data locality breaks with a small number of mappers

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have a 16-node cluster running Hadoop 2.6.0 and an 8GB wordcount dataset, split into 8 files. Each file consists of 8 128MB HDFS blocks and all blocks for a single file are stored on a single machine (e.g. blocks 1-8 of file 1 are stored on node 1). Let's assume files 1-8 are stored on nodes 1-8 and nodes 9-16 don't store any data.

I would expect that when running the wordcount job with a minimum split size of 1GB I'll get 8 map tasks running on nodes 1-8. However, map tasks seem to run on arbitrary nodes (some are data-local but some only rack-local). The servers are not running any other jobs. Once I run the same job on a 16GB dataset (with nodes 9-16 now also each storing a 1GB file), I get perfect locality.

I was reading the code of `FileInputFormat`, in particular the `getSplits` and `getSplitHostsAndCachedHosts` methods but from that it seems that when all the blocks for a split are stored on the same node, the preferred location for that split should always be that node.

The setup might seem a bit artificial (it's for experimentation) but the question remains, why does Hadoop not schedule the map tasks where the files are when I have less tasks than nodes? I'm using the `FairScheduler` but observed the same behavior with the `CapacityScheduler`.

Comment: First thing I would check is how the blocks have been distributed across the DNs using: `hdfs fsck / -files -blocks -locations`. If that is very uneven then it may begin to explain why there are non-local reads happening.

Comment: Also note that if you increase the minimum split size above the block size then each mapper will be doing non-local reads for the blocks of the split that are not on that machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! All blocks of a single file are stored on only one node (I also just double-checked that with fsck). That's why I'd expect the map tasks for file A to run on the node that stores all the blocks for A. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.